# debian no wifi button and no wlan0

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, internet

Recently installed debian and i have no wifi and wlan0

output of `ifconfig`:

```
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.193  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::5648:10ff:feca:63f9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 54:48:10:ca:63:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 90224  bytes 95178748 (90.7 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 62997  bytes 7432087 (7.0 MiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 8  bytes 396 (396.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

output of `lspci -nn | grep Wireless`:

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac 
Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to install proprietary drivers, go to [Debian download Page for firmware-atheros_20161130-5_all.deb](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/all/firmware-atheros/download), and download the drivers from any link in there, you will get a .deb file, open the terminal and cd into the directory where you downloaded it, and do the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i "the file".deb

sudo apt-get install -f
```

you might need to restart the system.